# Rancher: creating hosts on AWS EC2

Tags: docker-machine, rancher

I'm trying to add a EC2 host to my Rancher setup. I have seen [this](http://docs.rancher.com/os/running-rancheros/cloud/aws/) tutorial, however I wanted to use Docker-machine instead.

To that extend, I have done the following:

```
MAC:~ user1$ docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-84fd6de0 --amazonec2-region eu-west-1 --amazonec2-ami ami-c5f1beb6  Rancher-node-aws-01Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(Rancher-node-aws-01) Launching instance...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...

Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Note: the AMI ID corresponds to rancheros-v0.7.0-hvm-1.

As you can see, I cannot SSH into the RancherOS (SSH port is open on AWS). Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use an SSH user called 'rancher'. So the full command will be:

```
docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-84fd6de0 --amazonec2-region eu-west-1 --amazonec2-ami ami-c5f1beb6 --amazonec2-ssh-user rancher Rancher-node-aws-01
```

Comment: Current AMI for each region can be found here: https://rancher.com/docs/os/v1.x/en/installation/amazon-ecs/#amazon-ecs-enabled-amis

Comment: Use this command for cheapest region:
    docker-machine create -d amazonec2 --amazonec2-region us-east-1 --amazonec2-ami ami-0f5cc7a532c3171c3 --amazonec2-ssh-user rancher Rancher-node-aws-01